# intellij ulltimate 2020.2 is not able to recognize the essential annotations?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, annotations, project

i lately updated my intellij ulltimate to the version 2020.2
and it is no longer able to:

- Recognize the essential annotations such us @SpringBootApplication when i create new projects !
- Recognize the main application of any old or downloaded project (from git for example)!
  i tried reimporting the modules ,rebuild the project and  uninstalling then installing it but still not working
  so i really can't use it anymore ?
  if there is some one who had the same issue ?
  if yes how can i solve it ?

Comment: Have you checked if your build tools are enabled through the plugin menu?